# How to delete one items in List C#?

Tags: c#

I have `List<String>` include nine items.

I want to delete at item contains: `&nbsp;`.

I do this with code:

```
foreach (string text in listHeader[0])
{
    if (text.Contains("&nbsp"))
    {
        listHeader[0] = listHeader[0].SelectMany(line =>
                                       {
                                           line.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
                                           return new String[] { line };
                                       }).ToList();
    }
}
```

But `listHeader[0]` also have nine items. How to fix my code to delete item contains `&nbsp;`.

Sample data:

```
listHeader[0]= {
                   text
                   sample
                   new string
                   &nbsp;
               }
```

Another case my `listHeader[1]` need filter with start with `<!--<div` to `</div>-->`.

```
foreach (string text in listHeader[1])
{
    listHeader[1] = Regex.Replace(text, "<!--<div.*?</div>-->", "").ToList();
}
```

My question is:

How to remove item contains string start with `<!--<div` and end at `</div>-->`

Sample:

```
listHeader[1] = {
go to school

<!--<div id='fav_0118668891'class='icon displayOn' ><span class='favorite' onclick='javascript:addMatchFavorites("0118668891","014018",false,false);' title='undefined'></span></div>-->

work at the company

take a coffee
}
```

My resolve:

In this case:

I using `StartWith` and `EndWith` to find this string and `Remove`.

```
listHeader[1].RemoveAll(x => x.StartsWith("<!--<div") && x.EndsWith("</div>-->"));
```

Comment: sample input please

Comment: Your code is pretty much unreadable :) I still do not understand what is the structure of your arrays. You said `List<String>`, but it actually looks like a list of lists. Could you show the whole code?

Comment: By the way, here `line.Replace("&nbsp;", "");` return value is simply ignored. `Replace` does not change original string, it returns a new modified.

Comment: How to remove item contains string start with <!--<div and end at </div>-->? I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in listHeader[0])
{
    if (item.Contains("&nbsp"))
        nineItems.Remove(item); // remove item(s) containing &nbsp
}
```

OR a simpler way:

```
listHeader[0].RemoveAll(x => x.Contains("&nbsp"));
```

Comment: My `listHeader[0]` contains start with `<!--<div` to `</div>-->`. Method `Contains` seem detected from to.

Comment: @VănLộc Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

> How to fix my code to delete item contains `&nbsp;`

You could use [`List.RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) method which removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.

```
listHeader[0].RemoveAll(x=> x.Contains("&nbsp"));
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a3sY45)

Comment: Thanks, @hari prasad.